# Why can't I access HingeJoint2D through script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm building a Unity 2d game, when I add a HingeJoint component to a 3d gameobject like cube or sphere, I can access it through script like `gameObject.hingerJoint.connectedBody = otherGameObject.rigibody;`. But I can not access the HingeJoint2D component when I add it into a 2d gameObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just means they haven't added an explicit shorthand for it. You can still get it just as easily and quickly by using `gameObject.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>()`. Using `gameObject.hingeJoint` is equivalent to using `gameObject.GetComponent<HingeJoint>()`.

EDIT: Sorry, that was C#. In unityscript it's `gameObject.GetComponent(HingeJoint2D)`.